# `push {r3, lr}` not executed on ARM A9

Tags: assembly, arm, u-boot, imx6

trying to get a u-boot v2022.04 up and running on a MCIMX6S7 (iMX6 Solo).

The issue is that it does not step after `push    {r3, lr}`, does not execute the push (no change in stack) and keep repeating the same instruction (no update in PC).

Debugging via JLink, I added below some GDB logs and a comparison btw the original OEM (old U-boot) and the new one.

Can anybody explain why this is happening and how to solve?

Regards,
AaWNSD

```
<gdb_log>
Breakpoint 1, s_init () at arch/arm/mach-imx/mx6/soc.c:615
615     if (is_mx6sx() || is_mx6ul() || is_mx6ull() || is_mx6sll())
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x17802200 <s_init>: push    {r3, lr}
Dump of assembler code for function s_init:
=> 0x17802200 <+0>: push    {r3, lr}
   0x17802202 <+2>: bl  0x17801e88 <get_cpu_rev>
   0x17802206 <+6>: ubfx    r0, r0, #12, #9
   0x1780220a <+10>:    cmp r0, #98 ; 0x62
   0x1780220c <+12>:    beq.n   0x1780228e <s_init+142>
   0x1780220e <+14>:    bl  0x17801e88 <get_cpu_rev>
   0x17802212 <+18>:    ubfx    r0, r0, #12, #9
   0x17802216 <+22>:    cmp r0, #100    ; 0x64
   0x17802218 <+24>:    beq.n   0x1780228e <s_init+142>
   0x1780221a <+26>:    bl  0x17801e88 <get_cpu_rev>
   0x1780221e <+30>:    ubfx    r0, r0, #12, #9
   0x17802222 <+34>:    cmp r0, #101    ; 0x65
   0x17802224 <+36>:    beq.n   0x1780228e <s_init+142>
   0x17802226 <+38>:    bl  0x17801e88 <get_cpu_rev>
   0x1780222a <+42>:    ubfx    r0, r0, #12, #9
   0x1780222e <+46>:    cmp r0, #107    ; 0x6b
   0x17802230 <+48>:    beq.n   0x1780228e <s_init+142>
   0x17802232 <+50>:    bl  0x17801e88 <get_cpu_rev>
   0x17802236 <+54>:    ubfx    r0, r0, #12, #9
   0x1780223a <+58>:    cmp r0, #103    ; 0x67
   0x1780223c <+60>:    beq.n   0x1780228e <s_init+142>
   0x1780223e <+62>:    ldr r3, [pc, #120]  ; (0x178022b8 <s_init+184>)
   0x17802240 <+64>:    ldr r2, [r3, #24]
   0x17802242 <+66>:    dmb sy
   0x17802246 <+70>:    ubfx    r3, r2, #21, #2
   0x1780224a <+74>:    cmp r3, #2
   0x1780224c <+76>:    ubfx    r2, r2, #18, #2
   0x17802250 <+80>:    beq.n   0x1780229a <s_init+154>
   0x17802252 <+82>:    cmp r2, #2
   0x17802254 <+84>:    beq.n   0x178022a4 <s_init+164>
   0x17802256 <+86>:    cmp r3, #1
   0x17802258 <+88>:    beq.n   0x17802296 <s_init+150>
   0x1780225a <+90>:    cmp r2, #1
   0x1780225c <+92>:    beq.n   0x17802296 <s_init+150>
   0x1780225e <+94>:    cmp r3, #3
   0x17802260 <+96>:    ldr r3, [pc, #88]   ; (0x178022bc <s_init+188>)
   0x17802262 <+98>:    beq.n   0x17802268 <s_init+104>
   0x17802264 <+100>:   cmp r2, #3
   0x17802266 <+102>:   bne.n   0x178022b0 <s_init+176>
   0x17802268 <+104>:   dmb sy
   0x1780226c <+108>:   mov.w   r1, #2155905152 ; 0x80808080
   0x17802270 <+112>:   ldr r2, [pc, #76]   ; (0x178022c0 <s_init+192>)
   0x17802272 <+114>:   str.w   r1, [r2, #244]  ; 0xf4
   0x17802276 <+118>:   dmb sy
   0x1780227a <+122>:   str.w   r3, [r2, #260]  ; 0x104
   0x1780227e <+126>:   dmb sy
   0x17802282 <+130>:   str.w   r1, [r2, #248]  ; 0xf8
   0x17802286 <+134>:   dmb sy
   0x1780228a <+138>:   str.w   r3, [r2, #264]  ; 0x108
   0x1780228e <+142>:   pop {r3, pc}
   0x17802290 <+144>:   mov.w   r3, #2147516416 ; 0x80008000
   0x17802294 <+148>:   b.n 0x17802264 <s_init+100>
   0x17802296 <+150>:   ldr r3, [pc, #36]   ; (0x178022bc <s_init+188>)
   0x17802298 <+152>:   b.n 0x17802268 <s_init+104>
   0x1780229a <+154>:   cmp r2, #1
   0x1780229c <+156>:   bne.n   0x17802290 <s_init+144>
   0x1780229e <+158>:   mov.w   r3, #2147516416 ; 0x80008000
   0x178022a2 <+162>:   b.n 0x17802268 <s_init+104>
   0x178022a4 <+164>:   cmp r3, #1
   0x178022a6 <+166>:   beq.n   0x1780229e <s_init+158>
   0x178022a8 <+168>:   cmp r3, #3
   0x178022aa <+170>:   beq.n   0x1780229e <s_init+158>
   0x178022ac <+172>:   mov.w   r3, #2147516416 ; 0x80008000
   0x178022b0 <+176>:   orr.w   r3, r3, #8388608    ; 0x800000
   0x178022b4 <+180>:   b.n 0x17802268 <s_init+104>
   0x178022b6 <+182>:   nop
   0x178022b8 <+184>:   andeq   r4, r12, #0
   0x178022bc <+188>:   andhi   r8, r0, r0, lsl #1
   0x178022c0 <+192>:   andeq   r8, r12, #0
End of assembler dump.
r0             0x93ff20            9699104
r1             0x412fc09a          1093648538
r2             0x2a                42
r3             0x2                 2
r4             0xa                 10
r5             0x17800320          394265376
r6             0x20d8000           34439168
r7             0x94                148
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x93fe40            9698880
r10            0x0                 0
r11            0x0                 0
r12            0x0                 0
sp             0x93fe38            0x93fe38
lr             0x17800668          394266216
pc             0x17802200          0x17802200 <s_init>
cpsr           0x800001f3          2147484147
fpscr          0x6a0a4461          1779057761
r8_usr         0x0                 0
r9_usr         0x93fe40            9698880
r10_usr        0x0                 0
r11_usr        0x0                 0
r12_usr        0x0                 0
r13_usr        0x0                 0
r14_usr        0x0                 0
r8_fiq         0x0                 0
r9_fiq         0x0                 0
r10_fiq        0x0                 0
r11_fiq        0x0                 0
r12_fiq        0x0                 0
r13_fiq        0x0                 0
r14_fiq        0x0                 0
spsr_fiq       0x90090738          2416510776
r13_irq        0x0                 0
r14_irq        0x0                 0
spsr_irq       0x4030407           67306503
r13_svc        0x93fe38            9698872
r14_svc        0x17800668          394266216
spsr_svc       0x6a0a4461          1779057761
r13_abt        0x0                 0
r14_abt        0x0                 0
spsr_abt       0x40d003e           67960894
r13_und        0x0                 0
r14_und        0x0                 0
spsr_und       0xf45c8             1000904
#0  s_init () at arch/arm/mach-imx/mx6/soc.c:615
#1  0x17800668 in lowlevel_init () at arch/arm/cpu/armv7/lowlevel_init.S:67
#2  0x17800324 in save_boot_params_ret () at arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.S:124
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Breakpoint 1, s_init () at arch/arm/mach-imx/mx6/soc.c:615
615     if (is_mx6sx() || is_mx6ul() || is_mx6ull() || is_mx6sll())
1: x/i $pc
=> 0x17802200 <s_init>: push    {r3, lr}
r0             0x93ff20            9699104
r1             0x412fc09a          1093648538
r2             0x2a                42
r3             0x2                 2
r4             0xa                 10
r5             0x17800320          394265376
r6             0x20d8000           34439168
r7             0x94                148
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x93fe40            9698880
r10            0x0                 0
r11            0x0                 0
r12            0x0                 0
sp             0x93fe38            0x93fe38
lr             0x17800668          394266216
pc             0x17802200          0x17802200 <s_init>
cpsr           0x800001f3          2147484147
fpscr          0x6a0a4461          1779057761
r8_usr         0x0                 0
r9_usr         0x93fe40            9698880
r10_usr        0x0                 0
r11_usr        0x0                 0
r12_usr        0x0                 0
r13_usr        0x0                 0
r14_usr        0x0                 0
r8_fiq         0x0                 0
r9_fiq         0x0                 0
r10_fiq        0x0                 0
r11_fiq        0x0                 0
r12_fiq        0x0                 0
r13_fiq        0x0                 0
r14_fiq        0x0                 0
spsr_fiq       0x90090738          2416510776
r13_irq        0x0                 0
r14_irq        0x0                 0
spsr_irq       0x4030407           67306503
r13_svc        0x93fe38            9698872
r14_svc        0x17800668          394266216
spsr_svc       0x6a0a4461          1779057761
r13_abt        0x0                 0
r14_abt        0x0                 0
spsr_abt       0x40d003e           67960894
r13_und        0x0                 0
r14_und        0x0                 0
spsr_und       0xf45c8             1000904
#0  s_init () at arch/arm/mach-imx/mx6/soc.c:615
#1  0x17800668 in lowlevel_init () at arch/arm/cpu/armv7/lowlevel_init.S:67
#2  0x17800324 in save_boot_params_ret () at arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.S:124
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
quit
</gdb_log>

<uboot_trace>
=> 0x17800000 <_start>: b   0x178002e8 <reset>
=> 0x178002e8 <reset>:  b   0x17800338 <save_boot_params>
=> 0x17800338 <save_boot_params>:   b   0x178002ec <save_boot_params_ret>
=> 0x178002ec <save_boot_params_ret>:   mrs r0, CPSR
=> 0x178002f0 <save_boot_params_ret+4>: and r1, r0, #31
=> 0x178002f4 <save_boot_params_ret+8>: teq r1, #26
=> 0x178002f8 <save_boot_params_ret+12>:    bicne   r0, r0, #31
=> 0x178002fc <save_boot_params_ret+16>:    orrne   r0, r0, #19
=> 0x17800300 <save_boot_params_ret+20>:    orr r0, r0, #192    ; 0xc0
=> 0x17800304 <save_boot_params_ret+24>:    msr CPSR_fc, r0
=> 0x17800308 <save_boot_params_ret+28>:    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr1, cr0, {0}
=> 0x1780030c <save_boot_params_ret+32>:    bic r0, r0, #8192   ; 0x2000
=> 0x17800310 <save_boot_params_ret+36>:    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr1, cr0, {0}
=> 0x17800314 <save_boot_params_ret+40>:    ldr r0, [pc, #132]  ; 0x178003a0
=> 0x17800318 <save_boot_params_ret+44>:    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, {0}
=> 0x1780031c <save_boot_params_ret+48>:    bl  0x1780033c <cpu_init_cp15>
=> 0x1780033c <cpu_init_cp15>:  mov r0, #0
=> 0x17800340 <cpu_init_cp15+4>:    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr8, cr7, {0}
=> 0x17800344 <cpu_init_cp15+8>:    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr7, cr5, {0}
=> 0x17800348 <cpu_init_cp15+12>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr7, cr5, {6}
=> 0x1780034c <cpu_init_cp15+16>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr7, cr10, {4}
=> 0x17800350 <cpu_init_cp15+20>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr7, cr5, {4}
=> 0x17800354 <cpu_init_cp15+24>:   mrc 15, 0, r0, cr1, cr0, {0}
=> 0x17800358 <cpu_init_cp15+28>:   bic r0, r0, #8192   ; 0x2000
=> 0x1780035c <cpu_init_cp15+32>:   bic r0, r0, #7
=> 0x17800360 <cpu_init_cp15+36>:   orr r0, r0, #2
=> 0x17800364 <cpu_init_cp15+40>:   orr r0, r0, #2048   ; 0x800
=> 0x17800368 <cpu_init_cp15+44>:   orr r0, r0, #4096   ; 0x1000
=> 0x1780036c <cpu_init_cp15+48>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr1, cr0, {0}
=> 0x17800370 <cpu_init_cp15+52>:   mrc 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x17800374 <cpu_init_cp15+56>:   orr r0, r0, #64 ; 0x40
=> 0x17800378 <cpu_init_cp15+60>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x1780037c <cpu_init_cp15+64>:   mov r5, lr
=> 0x17800380 <cpu_init_cp15+68>:   mrc 15, 0, r1, cr0, cr0, {0}
=> 0x17800384 <cpu_init_cp15+72>:   lsr r3, r1, #20
=> 0x17800388 <cpu_init_cp15+76>:   and r3, r3, #15
=> 0x1780038c <cpu_init_cp15+80>:   and r4, r1, #15
=> 0x17800390 <cpu_init_cp15+84>:   lsl r2, r3, #4
=> 0x17800394 <cpu_init_cp15+88>:   orr r2, r4, r2
=> 0x17800398 <cpu_init_cp15+92>:   mov pc, r5
=> 0x17800320 <save_boot_params_ret+52>:    bl  0x1780039c <cpu_init_crit>
=> 0x1780039c <cpu_init_crit>:  b   0x1780064c <lowlevel_init>
=> 0x1780064c <lowlevel_init>:  ldr sp, [pc, #24]   ; 0x1780066c
=> 0x17800650 <lowlevel_init+4>:    bic sp, sp, #7
=> 0x17800654 <lowlevel_init+8>:    sub sp, sp, #224    ; 0xe0
=> 0x17800658 <lowlevel_init+12>:   bic sp, sp, #7
=> 0x1780065c <lowlevel_init+16>:   mov r9, sp
=> 0x17800660 <lowlevel_init+20>:   push    {r12, lr}
=> 0x17800664 <lowlevel_init+24>:   blx 0x17802200 <s_init>
=> 0x17802200 <s_init>: push    {r3, lr}
</uboot_trace>

<OEM_uboot_trace>
=> 0x17800000 <_start>: b   0x178002e8 <reset>
=> 0x178002e8 <reset>:  b   0x17800338 <save_boot_params>
=> 0x17800338 <save_boot_params>:   b   0x178002ec <save_boot_params_ret>
=> 0x178002ec <save_boot_params_ret>:   mrs r0, CPSR
=> 0x178002f0 <save_boot_params_ret+4>: and r1, r0, #31
=> 0x178002f4 <save_boot_params_ret+8>: teq r1, #26
=> 0x178002f8 <save_boot_params_ret+12>:    bicne   r0, r0, #31
=> 0x178002fc <save_boot_params_ret+16>:    orrne   r0, r0, #19
=> 0x17800300 <save_boot_params_ret+20>:    orr r0, r0, #192    ; 0xc0
=> 0x17800304 <save_boot_params_ret+24>:    msr CPSR_fc, r0
=> 0x17800308 <save_boot_params_ret+28>:    mrc 15, 0, r0, cr1, cr0, {0}
=> 0x1780030c <save_boot_params_ret+32>:    bic r0, r0, #8192   ; 0x2000
=> 0x17800310 <save_boot_params_ret+36>:    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr1, cr0, {0}
=> 0x17800314 <save_boot_params_ret+40>:    ldr r0, [pc, #180]  ; 0x178003d0
=> 0x17800318 <save_boot_params_ret+44>:    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr12, cr0, {0}
=> 0x1780031c <save_boot_params_ret+48>:    bl  0x1780033c <cpu_init_cp15>
=> 0x1780033c <cpu_init_cp15>:  mov r0, #0
=> 0x17800340 <cpu_init_cp15+4>:    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr8, cr7, {0}
=> 0x17800344 <cpu_init_cp15+8>:    mcr 15, 0, r0, cr7, cr5, {0}
=> 0x17800348 <cpu_init_cp15+12>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr7, cr5, {6}
=> 0x1780034c <cpu_init_cp15+16>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr7, cr10, {4}
=> 0x17800350 <cpu_init_cp15+20>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr7, cr5, {4}
=> 0x17800354 <cpu_init_cp15+24>:   mrc 15, 0, r0, cr1, cr0, {0}
=> 0x17800358 <cpu_init_cp15+28>:   bic r0, r0, #8192   ; 0x2000
=> 0x1780035c <cpu_init_cp15+32>:   bic r0, r0, #7
=> 0x17800360 <cpu_init_cp15+36>:   orr r0, r0, #2
=> 0x17800364 <cpu_init_cp15+40>:   orr r0, r0, #2048   ; 0x800
=> 0x17800368 <cpu_init_cp15+44>:   orr r0, r0, #4096   ; 0x1000
=> 0x1780036c <cpu_init_cp15+48>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr1, cr0, {0}
=> 0x17800370 <cpu_init_cp15+52>:   mrc 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x17800374 <cpu_init_cp15+56>:   orr r0, r0, #16
=> 0x17800378 <cpu_init_cp15+60>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x1780037c <cpu_init_cp15+64>:   mrc 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x17800380 <cpu_init_cp15+68>:   orr r0, r0, #64 ; 0x40
=> 0x17800384 <cpu_init_cp15+72>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x17800388 <cpu_init_cp15+76>:   mrc 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x1780038c <cpu_init_cp15+80>:   orr r0, r0, #2048   ; 0x800
=> 0x17800390 <cpu_init_cp15+84>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x17800394 <cpu_init_cp15+88>:   mrc 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x17800398 <cpu_init_cp15+92>:   orr r0, r0, #2097152    ; 0x200000
=> 0x1780039c <cpu_init_cp15+96>:   mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x178003a0 <cpu_init_cp15+100>:  mrc 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x178003a4 <cpu_init_cp15+104>:  orr r0, r0, #4194304    ; 0x400000
=> 0x178003a8 <cpu_init_cp15+108>:  mcr 15, 0, r0, cr15, cr0, {1}
=> 0x178003ac <cpu_init_cp15+112>:  mov r5, lr
=> 0x178003b0 <cpu_init_cp15+116>:  mrc 15, 0, r1, cr0, cr0, {0}
=> 0x178003b4 <cpu_init_cp15+120>:  lsr r3, r1, #20
=> 0x178003b8 <cpu_init_cp15+124>:  and r3, r3, #15
=> 0x178003bc <cpu_init_cp15+128>:  and r4, r1, #15
=> 0x178003c0 <cpu_init_cp15+132>:  lsl r2, r3, #4
=> 0x178003c4 <cpu_init_cp15+136>:  orr r2, r4, r2
=> 0x178003c8 <cpu_init_cp15+140>:  mov pc, r5
=> 0x17800320 <save_boot_params_ret+52>:    bl  0x178003cc <cpu_init_crit>
=> 0x178003cc <cpu_init_crit>:  b   0x178003d4 <lowlevel_init>
=> 0x178003d4 <lowlevel_init>:  ldr sp, [pc, #16]   ; 0x178003ec
=> 0x178003d8 <lowlevel_init+4>:    bic sp, sp, #7
=> 0x178003dc <lowlevel_init+8>:    mov r9, #0
=> 0x178003e0 <lowlevel_init+12>:   push    {r12, lr}
=> 0x178003e4 <lowlevel_init+16>:   bl  0x17800a90 <s_init>
=> 0x17800a90 <s_init>: push    {r3, lr}
=> 0x17800a94 <s_init+4>:   bl  0x17800700 <get_cpu_rev>
=> 0x17800700 <get_cpu_rev>:    ldr r2, [pc, #92]   ; 0x17800764 <get_cpu_rev+100>
=> 0x17800708 <get_cpu_rev+8>:  ubfx    r0, r3, #16, #8
</OEM_uboot_trace>
```

Some update.

I am not sure how the ARM Thumb stuff works and why this is happening, but comparing the OEM u-boot.imx, with "mine" (different u-boot ver, u-boot CI compiler) I noticed there is a `blx s_init`, instead of a `bl s_init`, switching to Thumb.

[image]

On the next instruction, where execution hangs, THUMB bit is active and $pc has a 1 delta with the instruction. Normal?

[image]

Comment: Something wrong with debugger ? `push {r3, lr}` might fail if you are running out of stack and mapped memory. But in this case you should jump to exception handler.

Comment: Hi, thanks. How can I check and fix this? GDB+JLink seems ok otheriwse (debugging ok other execs) and device in normal mode does not work with this executable

Answer (score 1):

so the long story short is: GDB 12.1 + JLink V7.64e on iMX6S (ARM7a, Cortex-A9) is messy.

At least while debugging U-boot 2022, using mixed ARM/Thumb compiled code, breaks and steps do not work (core dumps or hanging of the debugger). While debugging with Segger Ozone + JLink works fine (too bad, gdb would be best ot use), you only need to properly init the processor, see: https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors-Knowledge-Base/Bring-up-i-MX6-via-JTAG/ta-p/1124954

Cheers,
AaWNSD

Comment: One more: updating to fesh latest JLink: 770e made things work (four months back version was not working)